# C - Fourier transform series for a sawtooth wave

Tags: c, ios, fft, audiounit, waveform

I am building an iOS synth, using Audio Unit, basically built around [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html).

I already support a simple ASR envelope, and sine, triangle and square waves.

Sine are simply,

```
 sin(theta) * amplitude
```

Squares are

```
 sgn(sin(theta)) * amplitude
```

Now triangles use a non-looped FFT, as follows:

```
((8 / pow(M_PI,2)) * (sin(theta) - sin(3*theta)/9 + sin(5*theta)/25)) * amplitude
```

But I can't figure out the sawtooth waves,
I have tried `2*(theta - floor(theta) - 0.5)` but it came out aliased and distorted(not from clipping).
I now I should build it with a Fourier transform series, but I can't figure out how to implement it in C.

Any help anyone?

Comment: Why are you using a Fourier series for this?  Anyway, the Fourier series for a sawtooth is given at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Example_1:_a_simple_Fourier_series.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth becuase that the standart function has too many harmonics and it start to aliase and distort. I have seen it, but I can't understand how to implement it.

Comment: A triangle wave has the same harmonics as a square wave, they're just at different amplitudes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was talking about the sawtooth wave

Comment: Is it just me, or the sine and square signal is the same?

Comment: @H2CO3 just you, the square waves are the sign of the sine waves. see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: @H2CO3 : Yup.  The sine wave should not have an sgn() function in it.  Only the square.

Comment: @Mr.Awesome nope, apparently I was right. And I know what the signum function is, btw.

Comment: @H2CO3 oh, soory then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a truncated Fourier series for sawtooth waves just like you did for triangle waves, except for including the even harmonic terms as well the odd harmonic terms in the summation, and using a divisor equal to the harmonic number of each term instead of the square of such.

The more terms you use, the more the series approximation will look like a sawtooth, but the more high frequency content it will include.